# Java - Reading Writing Large Long Array Code

Tags: java

I am trying to write a large Long Array of size 400000000 into a file and then read it back. What code I am using is following:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile ;
import java.util.* ;

class Checks {
public static FileChannel channel;
public static MappedByteBuffer mbb;

public static void main(String[] args){
    try{


      long k[] = new long[400000000] ;
          for(int i = 0 ; i < 400000000 ; i++){
            k[i] = i ;
          }

    channel = new RandomAccessFile("abc.dat", "rw").getChannel();
        mbb = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 1 << 24);
        mbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

          for(int i = 0 ; i < 400000000 ;i++ ){
             getMbb().putLong(k[i]);
        }

        channel.close();

       long ks[] = new long[400000000] ;

        channel = new RandomAccessFile("abc.dat", "rw").getChannel();
        mbb = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 1 << 24);
        mbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        for(int r = 0 ; r < 400000000; r++){
            ks[r] = getMbb().getLong();
         }

             for(int r = 0 ; r < 400000000; r++){
                 if(k[r] != ks[r]){
                  System.out.println("Error at " + r);
                  break ;
                  }
              }


}
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }

    public static ByteBuffer getMbb() throws IOException {
        if (mbb.remaining() <= 0) {
            mbb = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, channel.size(), 1 << 24);
            mbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        }
        return mbb;
    }
}
```

However, this code is giving error that write and read array are not same. Can anybody help me why is this happening ?

Comment: Your getMbb() method doesn't make sense, and you don't need it. By definition mbb is already big enough, and mapping a new buffer from the end of the file just addresses empty space. And you don't need either of those arrays,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `getMbb()` method is broken. Every time you remap the chunk of the file in memory, you map to `channel.size()`. That only works while you are creating the file, but not when you are reading it. When you are reading the file, you map the "region" of the file that come *after* the end of the file, and that has random contents.

You will have to fix the remapping code to keep track of where in the file you already are.

Answer (score 2):

Try forcing the changes made to the mapped buffer to disk, before closing the channel:

```
 mbb.force();
```

This way, in case you're using a file stored on a local device, you have the guarantee that all the changes made to the mapped buffer will be reflected on disk.

Considering that you only append to the file, an alternative way of accomplishing what you want is:

```
  channel = new RandomAccessFile("abc.dat", "rw").getChannel();

  ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.SIZE/8 * 1001);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 400000000 ;i++ ){
     //write a number of byte to a ByteBuffer
      buffer.putLong(k[i]);
      if(i % 1000 == 0){
          channel.write(buffer);
          buffer.clear();
      }
   }
   channel.write(buffer);
   buffer.clear();
```

For reading:

```
    buffer.clear();
    int bytesCnt;
    while((bytesCnt = channel.read(buffer))!=-1){
    for(int r = 0 ; r < bytesCnt; r++){
        ks[r] = buffer.getLong();
     }
    }
```

Regarding performance: In applications doing I/O, the performance penalties are due to the number of seeks. Consequently the lower number of seeks, the higher the performance. This is equivalent to writing **as much data as possible** (<=> smaller number of flushes to disk; a flush mean, in fact, a seek) in a **sequential** manner.

In your scenario the data is written only in a sequential way (appending to the file), so the only aspect to worry about is the number of flushes to the disk; this number is inversely proportional to the size of the buffer. So you should try to increase the size of the buffer as much as possible.

Comment: did you do it in the getMbb method .. before re-mapping ?

Comment: I do it in getMbb() before re-mapping and before channel close also. giving error : "Error at 2097152" all time.

Comment: try increasing the heap size of the JVM: -Xms2000M -Xmx2000M

Comment: Did you try with 400 instead of 400000000 ?

Comment: Yah. That is executing properly.

Comment: What filesystem are you on? On older filesystems, files are limited to 2GB in size, which you exceed with such a huge array.

Comment: @Jochen, is above code is not giving error on your computer ?

Comment: I think it's pretty difficult to run this program on a standard machine; you set the heap size at 24576M !!!

Comment: @Razvan, is there another way to implement above ?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. The array is about 3.2GB, so as long as you have something like 4GB of memory, this thing should run fine. But it does take a very long time.

Comment: @Jochen, for me it is taking less than 2 min. BTW, is there another way to implement above ? Means with same efficiency ?

Comment: @Arpssss: Why do you want to map the file in memory. I see that you only append. Why don't you write to the channel directly ?

Comment: @Razvan, can you kindly illustrate it with example what you trying to mean ?

Comment: @Razvan,  Thanks a lot and how to read it ? And another point is is this will be as fast as my OP code ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'd suggest:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  File f = new File("abc.txt");

  DataOutputStream s = new DataOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(f));

  for ( int i = 0; i < 400000000; i++ ) {
    s.writeLong(i);
  }
  s.close();

  DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream( new FileInputStream(f));
  for (int i = 0; i < 400000000; i++ ) {
    if ( i != is.readLong() ) System.out.println("Error at " + i);
  }
}
```

This does all your program does, but without allocating memory explicitly and certainly without duplicating that allocation through a memory mapped buffer.
If this solution actually applies to what you really want to do is hard to tell, as you didn't say what this is for.

Comment: Actually, I want to make my code as fast as possible. I don't think DOS will be fast enough like FC and MBB.

Comment: That really depends. To figure out what will make you code work in practice, you have to have a realistic workload. Since your program is clearly just a toy example, this question makes limited sense.

Answer (score 1):

I modified a bit your code to use [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) and [DataOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) instead of RandomAccessFile and it works like a charm.

```
    try {
        long k[] = new long[400000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
            k[i] = i;
        }

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("abc.dat"));
        for (int i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
            dos.writeLong(k[i]);
        }

        long ks[] = new long[k.length];

        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("abc.dat"));

        for (int r = 0; r < ks.length; r++) {
            ks[r] = dis.readLong();
        }

        for (int r = 0; r < k.length; r++) {
            if (k[r] != ks[r]) {
                System.out.println("Error at " + r);
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
    } finally {
        // Make sure to close the streams
        dos.close();
        dis.close();
    }
```

Comment: Actually, I want to make my code as fast as possible. I don't think DOS will be fast enough like FC and MBB.